# What is the meaning of 女子大学生?

Tags: meaning

> この夏、新たな一歩を踏み出した**女子大学生**を取材しました。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0828.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_003))

1)a student of a women's college

or

2) a female university student

?

Comment: Have you tried translating it both ways to see which way makes more sense in context? It might translate well in both contexts, but which would be more appropriate given the action at the end of the sentence? (hint hint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

女子大学生 commonly means "female university students". "students of a women's college" is 女子大の学生.

Answer (score 0):

Both meanings are possible.

I think more than 50% of the present-day Japenese think it's 2).
But 2) includes 1) any way, doesn't it?